# Shiny Reactive calling itself

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, reactive

I was intending to create an implementation of the Hungarian Algorithm in R but was baffled by the behavior of a reactive function which from debugging using print statements appeared to be calling itself.

The reactive function that is not working is stepthree() and the rough gist of my code is passing a matrix to reactive functions which will perform the steps of the Hungarian algorithm and return the resultant matrix.

Here is the snippet of the reactive function:

```
stepthree <- reactive({
    num_lines <- number_of_lines();
    print("Step three");
    matrix_clean <- stepone(); #Taking a clean matrix from step one
    matrix <- steptwo(); #Taking the matrix which has lines drawn on it
    
    print("matrix_clean - clean matrix from step 1");
    print(matrix_clean);
    
    print("Matrix - dirty matrix from step 1");
    print(matrix);
    
    line_iteral <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow = 2*ncol(matrix))); #create a matrix to store the number of zeros in each row and column
    colnames(line_iteral) <- c("Position","Num","Type"); 
    lines_to_draw <- lines(); #Create another matrix to store the positions of the lines (1 means line, 0 means No line); row 1 is for "rows", row 2 is for "columns"
    print("Lines to draw");
    print(lines_to_draw);
    
    while(num_lines < ncol(matrix_clean)){
        
        print("No. of lines not the same!");
        smallest <- as.numeric(min(unlist(matrix))); #Take the smallest UNCOVERED value from the Matrix w lines on it (Gave the covered elements a very high value)
        print("Smallest:");
        print(smallest);
        for(i in 1:nrow(matrix_clean)){ #Subtract the smallest value from UNCOVERED entries and add the least value to COVERED entries
            for(j in 1:ncol(matrix_clean)){
                if(lines_to_draw[1,i] == 0 & lines_to_draw[2,j]==0){
                    matrix_clean[i,j] <- matrix_clean[i,j] - smallest;
                    print(paste("Subtracted smallest value of: ", toString(smallest), " to row ", toString(i), "and column", toString(j)));
                }
                else if(lines_to_draw[1,i] == 1 & lines_to_draw[2,j] == 1){
                    matrix_clean[i,j] <- matrix_clean[i,j] + smallest;
                    print(paste("Added smallest value of: ", toString(smallest), " to row ", toString(i), "and column", toString(j)));
                }
            }
        }
        print("Saving matrix_clean");
        matrix3(matrix_clean); #Store the untouched matrix in a reactive global var
        
        lines_to_draw[1,] <- 0; #Reset the matrix which stores the position of the lines
        lines_to_draw[2,] <- 0;
        
        print("matrix_clean - edited matrix");
        print(matrix_clean);
        for(i in 1:nrow(matrix_clean)){
            line_iteral[i,1] <- i;
            line_iteral[i,2] <- sum(matrix_clean[i,] == 0);
            line_iteral[i,3] <- c("Row");
        } #Sum up all the zeros in the rows
        for(j in 1:ncol(matrix_clean)){
            line_iteral[j+ncol(matrix_clean),1] <- j;
            line_iteral[j+ncol(matrix_clean),2] <- sum(matrix_clean[,j] == 0);
            line_iteral[j+ncol(matrix_clean),3] <- c("Col");
        } #Sum up all the zeros in the columns
        total_zeros <- sum(line_iteral[1:(ncol(matrix)),2]);
        print("line_iteral line 468: ");
        print(line_iteral);
        print("Total Zeros:");
        print(total_zeros);
        while(total_zeros > 0){
            largest <- line_iteral %>% slice(which.max(Num));
            #print(largest);
            if(largest[3] == "Row"){
                matrix_clean[as.numeric(largest[1]),] <- 99999999;
                lines_to_draw[1,as.numeric(largest[1])] <- 1;
            }
            else{
                matrix_clean[,as.numeric(largest[1])] <- 99999999;
                lines_to_draw[2,as.numeric(largest[1])] <- 1;
            }
            for(i in 1:nrow(matrix_clean)){
                line_iteral[i,1] <- i;
                line_iteral[i,2] <- sum(matrix_clean[i,] == 0);
                line_iteral[i,3] <- "Row"
            } #Sum up all the zeros in the rows
            for(j in 1:ncol(matrix_clean)){
                line_iteral[j+ncol(matrix_clean),1] <- j;
                line_iteral[j+ncol(matrix_clean),2] <- sum(matrix_clean[,j] == 0);
                line_iteral[j+ncol(matrix_clean),3] <- "Col";
            } #Sum up all the zeros in the columns
            total_zeros <- sum(line_iteral[1:ncol(matrix_clean),2]);
            print("Total Zeros");
            print(total_zeros);
        }
        #print(line_iteral)
        num_lines <- sum(lines_to_draw[1,]) + sum(lines_to_draw[2,]);
        print("Number of lines:");
        print(num_lines);
        print("Lines to draw:");
        print(lines_to_draw);
        matrix <- matrix_clean;
        matrix4(matrix_clean);
        matrix_clean <- matrix3();
        print("No of columns: ");
        print(ncol(matrix_clean))
        if(num_lines == ncol(matrix_clean)){
            break;
        }
        print("Rinse and Repeat: Looping");
    }
    return(matrix_clean); 
})
```

As for the UI I only call "stepthree()" once in the output section:

```
gg <- reactive({
    ggplot <- ggplot(data=coordinates(),mapping = aes(x="x", y="y")) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=coordinates()[,1], y=coordinates()[,2]));
    return(ggplot);
})
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    gg();
})
output$table <- renderTable({
    coordinates();
})
output$dist_matrix_x <- renderTable({
    distance_matrix_x();
})
output$dist_matrix_y <- renderTable({
    distance_matrix_y();
})
output$combined_matrix <- renderTable({
    combined_matrix();
})
output$stepone <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(stepone(),options = list(lengthMenu = c(100,1000,10000), pageLength = 100));
})
output$steptwo <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(transposed(), options = list(lengthMenu = c(100,1000,10000), pageLength = 100)) %>% formatStyle(colnames(lines_at_step_two())[lines_at_step_two()[2,]==1], backgroundColor = "yellow") %>% formatStyle(colnames(steptwo()), valueColumns = "transposed[, 1]", target = "row", backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1,0), c("yellow","white")));
})
output$stepthree <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(steptwo(), options = list(lengthMenu = c(100,1000,10000), pageLength = 100));
})
output$stepfour <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(stepthree(), options = list(lengthMenu = c(100,1000,10000), pageLength = 100)) 
})
output$stepfive <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(as.data.frame(matrix4()));
})
```

I have uploaded the full code [here](https://github.com/RCPilot1604/ME_TSP)

The general idea of the program is this:
stepone()

1. Takes a matrix from a previous function that returns a symmetrical matrix. Call this "matrix".
2. From "matrix", subtract the smallest value of each row from each row; and smallest value in each column from each column.
3. Return "matrix"

*As of now, this part works fine.*

steptwo():
(Attempt the draw the least number of lines possible to cover all the zeros)

1. Import the matrix from stepone(). Call this "matrix"
2. Find the sum of the number of zeros in the rows and in the columns in "matrix". Save this under a matrix called "line_iteral".
   **WHILE** (total_zeros > 0) {
3. Draw "lines" to cover all the zeros by choosing the row/column with the largest number of zeros and then replacing the entire row / column in "matrix" with a large value.
4. Store the positions of the lines in a matrix "lines_to_draw" which is saved to a global reactive variable lines() so that it can be used in stepthree()
5. Repeat Step 3 (Sum the number of zeros and save it to "line iteral")
6. Sum the total number of zeros (sum of either row in "line iteral" and save it to "total_zeros".

(Repeat steps 3-6 until total zeros = 0)
}
6. Sum the number of lines by finding the sum of entries in "lines_to_draw" and save it in a global variable "number_of_lines()
7. Return "matrix"

stepthree(): (Edit the matrix and repeat the process of covering zeros with the least number of lines until the number of lines = the number of columns

1. Import the result from steptwo(). Call this "matrix".
2. Import the result from stepone().  Call this matrix "matrix_clean".

**WHILE** (the number of lines drawn in steptwo() is smaller than the number of columns in the matrix){

3. Take the smallest value from "matrix" and store it as "smallest"
4. Take "matrix_clean", subtract "smallest" from all uncovered entries in "matrix_clean"
5. (coordinates where lines()[1,y] & lines()[2,x] == 0) and add it to all covered entries (coordinates where lines()[1,y] & lines()[2,x] == 1).
6. Save "matrix_clean" to a global reactive variable "matrix3"
7. Find the sum of the number of zeros in the rows and in the columns in "matrix". Save this under a matrix called "line_iteral".
   **WHILE** (total_zeros > 0) {
8. Draw "lines" to cover all the zeros by choosing the row/column with the largest number of zeros and then replacing the entire row/column in "matrix" with a large value.
9. Store the positions of the lines in a matrix "lines_to_draw".
10. Repeat Step 3 (Sum the number of zeros and save it to "line iteral")
11. Sum the total number of zeros (sum of either row in "line iteral" and save it to "total_zeros"
    }
    (Repeat the process of drawing a line and summing the zeros under no zeros remain)
12. Sum the number of lines by finding the sum of entries in "lines_to_draw" and save it in the global variable "number_of_lines()"
13. Let "matrix_clean" be "matrix3"
14. Let "matrix" be "matrix_clean"
    (Repeat steps 3 - 13 until the "number_of_lines" is equal to the number of columns of the "matrix_clean")
    }
15. Return the "matrix_clean" as the final answer.

The issue I met while running the code was that the reactive function stepthree() seemed to call itself as although "number_of_lines" and "ncol(matrix_clean)" were equal, debugging using print() showed me that for some reason the entire of stepthree was called again instead of returning the "matrix_clean" as final result. I am not sure if it is something I am doing wrongly with how reactive functions behave or perhaps this error stems from a systemic issue with the way I have designed the algorithm to run.

I apologize beforehand for the messy code as I am just starting out with R. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry, I haven't checked the complete code as it is too long, just a few comments: 1. I'm not sure if your issue is related to `shiny` or the code itself. I would encapsulate the complete code for the algorithm in own functions that you can test outside of `shiny`. When you made sure that it works, then you can add reactivity by calling these functions in `shiny`. 2. In `R`, loops can often be slow compared to using [vectorised functions](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html). 3. I would consider using `break` in an if loop as bad coding style

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the advice. I realized that the issue was with placing a reactive call in the while loop. Once I removed all the reactive calls in the while loop, everything worked as expected. : ) So yeah I think testing the algorithm outside of Shiny is a good idea.